# Get continues co-ordinates from drop element while hovering a draggable element over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hey guys I need to get the continuous co-ordinates of the element on which I hold a `draggable` element! Like `mousemove` which gives continuous co-ordinates but on draggable the `mousemove` is not triggering on the `droppable` element. So I tried out `over` of `droppable` which gives the co-ordinates only once. So is there any other way to get the `x,y` continuously on the element where I hold a `draggable` element over it !!!

```
over: function (event, ui) {
                var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY, DOM_ELEM_COORD = event.target.getBoundingClientRect(),
                placeHolder = wf_template.TEMPLATE_UTILITIES.DRAGDROP_API.placeholder.clone(); firstMove = false;
                $(placeHolder).mousemove(function (event) {
                    if ((event.clientY > (event.target.getBoundingClientRect().y + (event.target.getBoundingClientRect().height * (.20)))) || 
                        (event.clientY < ((event.target.getBoundingClientRect().y + (event.target.getBoundingClientRect().height * (.80))))))
                        event.target.remove();
                });
                console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
                var upper_Limit = DOM_ELEM_COORD.height * (.20), droppable_Limit = DOM_ELEM_COORD.height * (.60), lower_Limit = DOM_ELEM_COORD.height * (.80);                
                if (y < (DOM_ELEM_COORD.y + upper_Limit)) {
                    $(".draggable-placeholder").remove();
                    $(event.target).hasClass("workflow-info-row info-row-child") == true ? event.target.before(placeHolder[0]) : false;
                    firstMove = true;
                    console.log("top");
                } else if (y > (DOM_ELEM_COORD.y + upper_Limit) && y < (DOM_ELEM_COORD.y + droppable_Limit)) {
                    $(".draggable-placeholder").remove();
                    firstMove = false;
                    console.log("middle");
                } else if (y > (DOM_ELEM_COORD.y + lower_Limit)) {
                    $(".draggable-placeholder").remove();
                    $(event.target).hasClass("workflow-info-row info-row-child") == true ? event.target.after(placeHolder[0]) : false;
                    firstMove = false;
                    console.log("end");
                }
            },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You won't get this detail from droppable. I would get these details from draggable or the `drag` event. You can use droppable `over` and `out` to turn on and off the capture of these details.

Comment: @Twisty `over` and `out` might have helped if they give continuous co-ordinates. But it dosent

Comment: Please see the answer I posted for more clear explanation.

Comment: @Twisty ok. lemme ckeck

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of hard to give an example with the limited code you provided. Since draggable knows the drag position, it's easy to use this to gather the details you are looking for. Sounds like you only need them when the item is over the droppable, so we can keep a flag using `.data()` on the helper and report the detail to whatever function is needed.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.data("start-pos", ui.position);
      ui.helper.data("record", false);
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.helper.data("record")) {
        var pos = ui.position;
        var off = ui.offset;
        var ev = [
          event.clientX,
          event.clientY
        ];
        $("#log").html("<label>P:</label>[" + pos.left + "," + pos.top + "]<br /><label>O:</label>[" + off.left + "," + off.top + "]<br /><label>E:</label>[" + ev[0] + "," + ev[1] + "]");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.data("record", true);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.data("record", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

#log {
  width: 120px;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Courier, monospaced;
  font-size: .65em;
}

#log label {
display: inline-block;
width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="log" class="ui-widget-content">&nbsp;</div>
```

This is a very basic example, yet it should be enough to help clarify. You can also use `event` to collect details about mouse movement in the same way if you choose. I would also configure the [tolerance](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) to fit your needs too.

Hope that helps.